# Highcharts Network Graph Arrow Links

Tags: html, css, highcharts, bootstrap-4

I am trying to create a network graph using Highcharts as follows:

[image]

However, I did not see any options to add arrows instead of line segments connecting the nodes in the Highcharts network graph module. Is this possible to do this using Highcharts? If not, are there any better alternatives for this use case? Here is the code I currently have to render a network graph.

```
    eventWorkflowGraph = Highcharts.chart('graph-canvas', {
    chart: {
        type: 'networkgraph',
        spacingBottom: 15,
        spacingTop: 15,
        spacingLeft: 15,
        spacingRight: 15,
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Workflow'
    },
    subtitle: {
        text: 'Network Graph'
    },
    plotOptions: {
        networkgraph: {
            keys: ['from', 'to'],
            layoutAlgorithm: {
                friction: -0.9,
                linkLength: 100,
                enableSimulation: true
            },
            link: {
                width: 4
            }
        }
    },
    series: [{
        dataLabels: {
            enabled: true,
            linkFormat: '',
        },
        marker: {
            radius: 45
        },
        data: edges
    }]
});
```

This renders a network graph as follows:
[image]

Comment: Before I will try to implement those arrows I have a question, would you like to have those markers and links draggable or not? Because if not it will be easy to draw those arrows by using the SVGRenderer tool. https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.SVGRenderer#path

Comment: The links don't need to be draggable, only the nodes need to be draggable. Thanks!

Comment: On the SO or Highcharts forum you can find some examples of how to render the arrow on the end of the line, like this demo: http://jsfiddle.net/vyfsf1ft/. As you can see it requires to wrap the prototype function which renders path. Similar can be done for netwrokgraph: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/42mkqc7L/ it is not the wanted result, but could be a good start for you

Comment: Thanks so much! When you move the nodes around, the arrow seems to switch directions. Also, how would I make it so that the arrow tip touches the node instead of going through it?

Comment: I did some progress with the code - please take a look: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/ghocaedL/

Comment: And for this demo also: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/znpwdav4/

Comment: This is perfect! Just one small thing, I was trying to figure out in your code how to make the arrows show if the marker radius is bigger (my ideal radius is 45). Is that an easy fix?

Comment: I managed how to do it including radius value: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/cnjw7v2s/

Comment: Thanks! If there are two nodes (n1 and n2), and there are edges from n1 -> n2 and n2 -> n1, then the arrows overlap. Is there a way to make them parallel instead of on top of each other?

Comment: ` and there are edges from n1 -> n2 and n2 -> n1, then the arrows overlap` I a not sure if I understood this sentence. Are you able to reproduce this behaviour on the online editor?

Comment: Yes, here is the current behavior: https://jsfiddle.net/mer385jw/2/, and here is the behavior I would like to implement: https://ibb.co/dD82YYW

Comment: unfortunately, the current networkgraph implementation doesn't offer double links between nodes. You can report this idea on the Highcharts userVoice channel: https://highcharts.uservoice.com/forums/55896-highcharts-javascript-api or on the Highcharts GitHub issue channel: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues

Comment: Okay no problem. If you post the Jfiddle as an answer to this question, I can mark it as correct.

Comment: I posted the answer, could be useful for other users which will face same problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the comments - here is an answer on how to render the arrows at the end of the links in the networkgraph series.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/cnjw7v2s/

```
(function(H) {
  H.wrap(H.seriesTypes.networkgraph.prototype.pointClass.prototype, 'getLinkPath', function(p) {
    var left = this.toNode,
      right = this.fromNode;

    var angle = Math.atan((left.plotX - right.plotX) /
      (left.plotY - right.plotY));


    if (angle) {
      let path = ['M', left.plotX, left.plotY, right.plotX, right.plotY],
        lastPoint = left,
        nextLastPoint = right,
        pointRadius = 45,
        arrowLength = 20,
        arrowWidth = 10;

      if (left.plotY < right.plotY) {
        path.push(
          nextLastPoint.plotX - pointRadius * Math.sin(angle),
          nextLastPoint.plotY - pointRadius * Math.cos(angle),
        );
        path.push(
          nextLastPoint.plotX - pointRadius * Math.sin(angle) - arrowLength * Math.sin(angle) - arrowWidth * Math.cos(angle),
          nextLastPoint.plotY - pointRadius * Math.cos(angle) - arrowLength * Math.cos(angle) + arrowWidth * Math.sin(angle),
        );

        path.push(
          nextLastPoint.plotX - pointRadius * Math.sin(angle),
          nextLastPoint.plotY - pointRadius * Math.cos(angle),
        );
        path.push(
          nextLastPoint.plotX - pointRadius * Math.sin(angle) - arrowLength * Math.sin(angle) + arrowWidth * Math.cos(angle),
          nextLastPoint.plotY - pointRadius * Math.cos(angle) - arrowLength * Math.cos(angle) - arrowWidth * Math.sin(angle),
        );


      } else {
        path.push(
          nextLastPoint.plotX + pointRadius * Math.sin(angle),
          nextLastPoint.plotY + pointRadius * Math.cos(angle),
        );
        path.push(
          nextLastPoint.plotX + pointRadius * Math.sin(angle) + arrowLength * Math.sin(angle) - arrowWidth * Math.cos(angle),
          nextLastPoint.plotY + pointRadius * Math.cos(angle) + arrowLength * Math.cos(angle) + arrowWidth * Math.sin(angle),
        );
        path.push(
          nextLastPoint.plotX + pointRadius * Math.sin(angle),
          nextLastPoint.plotY + pointRadius * Math.cos(angle),
        );
        path.push(
          nextLastPoint.plotX + pointRadius * Math.sin(angle) + arrowLength * Math.sin(angle) + arrowWidth * Math.cos(angle),
          nextLastPoint.plotY + pointRadius * Math.cos(angle) + arrowLength * Math.cos(angle) - arrowWidth * Math.sin(angle),
        );

      }

      return path
    }
    return [
      ['M', left.plotX || 0, left.plotY || 0],
      ['L', right.plotX || 0, right.plotY || 0],
    ];
  });
}(Highcharts));
```