# Separating multiple links between network graph nodes

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts

I am building a network graph using HighCharts. Some of the nodes in the graph have multiple links between them, orientated differently (I am using an arrow-tip wrapper for the links, as described here : [Highcharts Network Graph Arrow Links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62903135/highcharts-network-graph-arrow-links)), and also styled differently (following the method described in an answer to a previous question of mine, here : [How do I customize link style for each data link in a Highcharts network graph?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69392552/how-do-i-customize-link-style-for-each-data-link-in-a-highcharts-network-graph)).

Because they are different and have different meanings, these links should not merge, but they do :

[Links merging ; note one solid and one dashed link merged together](https://i.stack.imgur.com/thso5.png)

Here is a JSFiddle demonstrating the issue :

https://jsfiddle.net/pqvemxsb/1/

This is the point of interest :

`data: [['PersonA','Software1','Activity1','Dot','teal'],['Software1','PersonA','Activity1','Solid','teal'],['PersonA','Software1','Activity2','Solid','red']]`

The red line obscures the teal line, the teal arrow shows at one end, and the dotted line is obscured entirely.

Is there any way to prevent this ? For instance, a way to curve each link so they are not overlapping straight lines ?

Comment: Could you reproduce your code with the sample data on some online editor?

Comment: @SebastianWędzel Yes, thank you for asking ! I will edit the original message to link to it. Here it is as well : https://jsfiddle.net/pqvemxsb/1/

You can see the three links only appearing as a single one. The teal solid arrow appears at the end of the red line, and the dotted line has been completely obscured.

Comment: thank you for the demo! I am afraid that multiple links are not supported in the network graph series. You can report this idea on the userVoice channel: https://highcharts.uservoice.com/forums/55896-highcharts-javascript-api or consider to use the renderer tool to implement this type of chart by yourself - demo: https://www.highcharts.com/demo/renderer

Comment: Thank you very much for your help ! I will definitely be submitting this feature to the user voice channel. Kind regards.